# Conditional query case MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a queries which select distinct id's and push them to the form. Then, in the form, I select data to display. After clicking submit I want the data to be shown. I found a problem creating some queries for fetching the data after clicking submit.

**1. The easy one:**

```
SELECT Distinct
    Data.data1.Model As model
```

Then in the form I get all distinct names of Models and I can choose appropriate ones. To show some other data, in a query I use:

```
SELECT something
FROM
WHERE
Data.data2.Model IN ('".implode("','",$model)."')
```

**2. The hard one:**

```
Select Distinct
    Case
        When Data.data3.data4 = '' Then '(blank)'
        When
        (Data.data3.data4 = 'Name21'
            Or Data.data3.data4 = 'Name23'
            Or Data.data3.data4 = 'Name256'
            Or Data.data3.data4 = 'Modeling part')
        Then
        'Name2'
        When Data.data3.data4 Like '%bugs%' Then '(bugs)'
        Else Data.data3.data4
    End As 'names'
```

I cannot use method mentioned in 1 case because when I `.implode` the `$names` I get all the names and `'(blank)'` and `Name2` and `(others)`

Any help implementing right code for the 2 case will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can,
First, replace every `str1` at your $model by `replaced-str1` and do it for every type you want to normalize.
Second, use `implode` as you intended for the rest of values.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your way. I am trying to do it with foreach() but now I am stuck, cause I don't know how to ommit some values.